# InfluxDB2, HTTP Basic Authentication to /api/v2 endpoints

Tags: basic-authentication, influxdb, flux, influxdb-2

- **Influx Version**: 2.7
- **OS**: RHEL9

when attempting to make a query via HTTP to influx, the below works;

```
curl -i -X POST https://<hostname>:8086/query?org=<redacted> -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.flux' -H 'Authorization: Basic <redacted>'
```

However, using basic auth for /api/v2 with the same query and content returns a 401.

```
curl -i -X POST https://<hostname>:8086/api/v2/query?org=<redacted> -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.flux' -H 'Authorization: Basic <redacted>'
```

The only successful authentication so far is from using a Token which with the infrastructure and how they are dynamically generated is not an option.

When performing the above on our previous Influx version (1.8), there is no issues going to /api/v2. Is there any configuration which is undocumented, where basic auth needs to be configured?

> all documentation has been exhausted & for example, the following explains that it is supported and *should* work; https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/api/#section/Authentication/BasicAuthentication

Comment: Facing the same issue now. Token authentication works fine while Basic one throws 401. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you tell us if you managed to solve the issue, or found a workaround?